# When is my service worker updated?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I can't seem to find in any documentation when my service worker will be updated?

Does it check for a new service worker file every time it is started, or once per day, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default it's checked every time the page is opened (https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md#updating-a-serviceworker).

You can force a check with the [ServiceWorkerRegistration.update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) method, that bypasses the HTTP cache if the previous check was more than one day ago.